# Sublime snippet to get a Title case field mirrored as a lowercase

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, code-snippets

I'm writing a sublimetext snippet, and I want to mirror a field, but get the mirrored field as a lowercase while the original field is in Title case.

```
getUser ('username', function(err, user){});
   ^^^^                            ^^^^
```

[Here](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html) it says that I could use perl regex but I don't know either enough to figure out
what would be the appropriate regex to achieve this?

```
get${1:User}('',function(err,${1/???/g}){});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing a simple replacement, you need a [format string](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/perl_format.html) to your regex, as discussed in the [snippets reference](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/snippets.html). So, your snippet should look like this:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
get${1:User} ('$2', function(err, ${1/(.*)/\L\1\E/i}){$0});
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>get</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.c</scope>
</snippet>
```

The regex matches all possible characters in variable `$1` (except newlines) and replaces it with itself but formats it in all lowercase (`\L` begins lowercasing, `\1` is the first capture group, and `\E` ends it). After it does that, hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> moves to `$2`, so you can enter that value if you wish. Hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> once more puts the cursor between the `{}` curly braces.

Make sure you set the `<scope>` to the appropriate language.

Comment: @laggingreflex - silly me - it should be working now. I forgot to make a capture group, and needed to place that between the beginning of the lowercasing and the end of it.